# Hide/Show Controls Notification for MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there a way to listen for changes in the player controls visibility for MPMoviePlayerController?

I have added two buttons to the container view above the MPMoviePlayerController view and it's controls.

I would like to hide/show these buttons in sync with when the player controls hide or show. I want the two buttons to look part of the players control bar.